# Are there performance issues with creating many anonymous classes?

Tags: java, performance

Are there any memory or speed issues with creating many anonymous inner classes?  In the following code, I like the succinctness of experiment1, but I am concerned that including anonymous class creation in a highly iterated loop would make it lose out to experiment2 for some dimension(s) of performance.

```
public class Test {
    interface Task {
        public void do();
    }

    public void experiment1 {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            Task inner = new Task() {public void do() {/* stuff */}}
        }
    }

    public void experiment2 {
        class InnerClass implements Task {
            public void do() {/* stuff */}
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            Task inner = new InnerClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried timing it?

Comment: If you compile that and inspect the bytecode, I expect you'll find that they are identical. In either case you have one .class file (for `Test$1` or `Test$InnerClass`). Within the loop you create an instance of the class.

Comment: You should prefer the succinctness of lambda expressions. Anonymous classes are no longer succinct.